# Expression choice: 'conclusion', 'taken as a whole', or 'regarding'

Tags: phrases, expressions, writing-style, expression-choice

I am wondering if it would be more effective to use another construction:

> **Taken as a whole**

or

> **Regarding**

instead of

> **In the general framework** of the leaf photosynthesis limitations associated with drought stress, we may conclude that leaf assimilation could have been reduced by increase in stomata and mesophyll resistance, elevation of the leaf temperature and negative feedback of carbohydrates.

Are these expressions all equivalent? Are there different levels of formality involved?

Comment: meta: This can be viewed as a question of expression-choice, why not?

Answer (score 1):

re·gard·ing (prep.)

In reference to; with respect to; concerning.

Certainly your work concerns itself with leaf photosynthesis limitations, so I would think "Regarding" or "Concerning" or "With respect to" would all be viable options.

(How scientific is this paper? Journal articles/papers usually follow a fairly strict structure, which the above does not follow.)

Comment: it is a Journal paper. What do you mean from my conclusion does not follow a strict structure?

Comment: But you still have to formulate what should be written under "Conclusions". They give you formate regulations, but not formulation regulations. (Some do for the abstract, but not down to "your sentence has to start with word A".)

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, the following sentence flows better, is more memorable, and is worded better:

> Regarding the limitations of leaf photosynthesis associated with drought stress, we may conclude that leaf assimilation could have been reduced in three ways:  an increase in stomata and mesophyll resistance, an elevation in the leaf temperature, and negative feedback in carbohydrates.

Comment: Ha! Now that *turns* that into a 'writing advice' question!

Comment: @Kris: Mea culpa. Mea maxima culpa. I take one look at the low reputation numbers of the OP and then jump right in. Must be my penchant for siding with underdogs and encouraging them to stay with us.  Don

Answer (score 0):

The use of *regarding* in that context would suggest a certain aspect, certainly not the 'general/ overall framework'. Your original composition is perfect.

> **In the general framework of** the leaf photosynthesis limitations associated with drought stress, we may conclude that …

— [This para summarizes everything presented in this paper on the subject of 'leaf photosynthesis limitations associated with drought stress'.]

vs.

> **Regarding** leaf photosynthesis limitations associated with drought stress, we may conclude that …

— [As far as the issue of ... is concerned, ]
or
— [Apart from the above, as for the issue of ... , ]
neither of these work with the 'we may conclude that' sense.